# Новые правила выведения шаблонного типа в c++17

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Что дают новые правила выведения шаблонного типа в c++17?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В c++17 появилась возможность опускать явное упоминание типов шаблонных параметров при объявлении переменной шаблонного типа. Например, для шаблонного типа `S`, конструктор которого принимает аргумент, зависимый от `T`:

```
template <class T>
struct S { 
    S(const T&) {}
};
```

можно использовать упрощённую запись, вида:

```
S si(42);  
S sl(42l); 
S sd(42.);
```

На первый взгляд кажется, что все переменные `si`, `sl`, `sd` имеют одинаковый тип. И если бы `S` не был шаблонным типом, это было бы действительно так. Но в данном случае, реальные типы переменных различны и выводятся из типа аргумента, переданного в конструктор. Эквивалентная запись для прежнего стандарта языка будет выглядеть так:

```
S<int>    si(42);  
S<long>   sl(42l); 
S<double> sd(42.);
```

Правда, указывая явно тип в треугольных скобках, нет особого смысла использовать разные типы в аргументах, т.е. можно везде использовать целое `42`.

Упомянутая выше логика компилятора опирается на неявное выведение типов (Implicit Deduction Guides). Но помимо этого есть и явное (Explicit Deduction Guides). В этом случае можно указать компилятору явно использовать некоторый целевой тип при попытке выведения типа. Например, если после определения шаблона класса добавить такую строку:

```
S(double) -> S<int>;
```

то это заставит компилятор выбирать тип `int` в качестве `T`, когда аргумент конструктора имеет тип `double`. Т.е. в этом случае, запись вида:

```
S sd(42.);
```

будет уже создавать переменную типа `S<int>`, а не `S<double>`. Объект типа `S<double>` по-прежнему можно будет создать, но тип придётся указывать явно.

О правилах выведения типов можно получить дополнительную информацию в черновике стандарта:

- [[temp.deduct.guide]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide)
- [[over.match.class.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct)

Comment: А так можно `auto si = new S(42);`?

Comment: @alexolut  Было бы хорошо, если бы вы указали, какой номер документа рабочего проекта стандарта C++ и от какого числа вы использовали при подготовке ответа.

Comment: @vp_arth угу. Можно даже `auto a = new auto(42)` :-D но это уже несколько иная история.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я добавил ссылки на черновик. Также я использовал черновик `N4618` от 2016-11-28.