# Оператор для нескольких объектов

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть ли в c++ возможность, позволяющая применять оператор для нескольких объектов? Короче, что-то типа этого:

```
int i = 5;
if (i == { 1, 2, 3, 5 } ) // if (i == 1 || i == 2 ...)
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Должен вас огорчить...

Comment: Просто сразу пришла идея, как это реализовать. Подумал, что лучше не писать велосипед, а поискать в интернете. Обидно, что нет такой возможности(

Comment: `int i = 3;
    auto al = {1,2,3,4,7,8};
    if (find(al.begin(),al.end(),i)!= al.end())
    {
        cout << "Found\n";
    }`
Но вряд ли вам это понравится :(

Comment: Можно еще через шаблоны, но будет не менее геморройно...

Comment: Я просто хотел весь поиск уложить в один перегруженный оператор==.
Пока знаю лишь как сделать это через функцию.

Comment: if (cmp(i, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 10 }))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В комментарий не помещаюсь...

Чтоб одним оператором и именно `==`

```
template<typename T>
class Has
{
private:
    vector<T> data;
public:
    explicit Has(initializer_list<T> lst):data(lst){}
    bool operator ==(const T& value) const
    {
        return find(data.cbegin(),data.cend(),value) == data.cend();
    }
};


template<typename T>
Has<T> in(initializer_list<T> lst)
{
    return Has<T>(lst);
}


int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    if (in({1,2,3,4,7,8}) == i) // Без in - if (Has<int>({1,2,3,4,7,8}) == i)
    {
        cout << "Found\n";
    }
}
```

Это путь чуть длиннее, но зато не нужно писать явно тип - ну, `in<int>`.

Если через функцию - то можно воспользоваться функцией с переменным числом аргументов.

Но стоит ли эта овчинка выделки?

Answer (score 5):

Непосредственно такой синтаксис не поддерживается. Чтобы реализовать нечто подобное без создания дополнительных классов можно использовать `std::set`:

```
if (std::set<int>{1, 2, 3, 5}.count(i))
{
   // ...
}
```

Если компилятор поддерживает c++17, то тип элементов `std::set` может быть выведен из списка инициализации и явное указание `<int>` не потребуется.

```
if (std::set{1, 2, 3, 5}.count(i))
{
   // ...
}
```

Подробнее об этом есть в соответствующем вопросе: [Новые правила выведения шаблонного типа в c++17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/636511/176217)